# Install android on PC

Tags: android

I recently started to learn to program on Android. I've only gotten in a couple of chapters in a book, but the emulator seems to run extremely slow. From what I found this is a general problem. I also found that there is a way to install android on a PC.
[install android on PC](http://www.ztuts.com/2012/05/how-to-install-android-on-pc-laptop-pro.html)

Could this solution prove a suitable test environment for a beginner developer?

Comment: You could also just develop on a real device...

Comment: It's on my to do list...as soon as I have the cash for it

Comment: Try setting up Eclipse with Bluestacks, I found it to be much faster and is a decent alternative, but you probably should just buy a used, cheap android device.... Droid 1 is decent!

Comment: Setup your propre development environment and use emulator. Just for reference if you want to install andro in PC read this link www.alltechstories.com/install-android-kitkat-on-a-pc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Bluestacks.

Set it up using these instructions from XDA-Developers.com

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1303563